# How to resolve error 'migration_group' entity with ID 'migrate_drupal_7' already exists?

Tags: migrations

I have been trying to migrate to Drupal 8 using the drush. I have followed all the instruction as mentioned in [https://drupalize.me/blog/201604/custom-drupal-drupal-migrations-migrate-tools][1]

After installation, enabled all the required modules like **migrate upgrade, migrate tools and migrate plus**, and then added the code in settings.php file mentioned below.

```
 // Database entry for `drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only`
$databases['upgrade']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'dbuser',
  'password' => 'dbpass',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
// Database entry for `drush migrate-import --all`
$databases['migrate']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'dbuser',
  'password' => 'dbpass',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Now used the command - `**drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only --legacy-db-url=mysql://dbuser:dbpass@localhost/dbname --legacy-root=/path/to/sites/default/files**` and than drush returns the following errors - `***'migration_group' entity with ID 'migrate_drupal_7' already exists***`

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can delete existing migration groups from: /admin/structure/migrate